# Find generating function for $H_k/k$

Tags: definite-integrals, generating-functions

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-z}\ln\frac{1}{1-z} &\to [z^k]A(z) = H_k\\
\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-z}\ln\frac{1}{1-z} &\to [z^k]A(z) = H_{k+1}
\end{align*}
So, now it is enought to integrate to get the generating function. And here my problems begin.

\begin{align*}
\int_0^z\frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{1-t}\ln\frac{1}{1-t}dt
\end{align*}

Which i don't know how to find.

**EDIT:**
Note that $\frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{1-t} = \frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{1-t}$. And i think i can find the following integral:

$$\int \frac{1}{1-t}\ln\frac{1}{1-t}dt = \frac{1}{2}\left(\ln\frac{1}{1-t}\right)^2$$

Funnily, MATLAB find the second integral involved:

```
>> f(z) = 1/z * log(1/(1-z))
ans(z) =
-dilog(-1/(z - 1)) - log(-1/(z - 1))^2/2
```

But how? And is at all right way to find the generating function.

Comment: What on Earth is $k$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier $k-$th coefficient in a series.

Comment: Um, mathlab didn't integrate it at all, it just rewrote `f(z)`. At least, from what you showed. Tried wolframalpha yet?

Comment: @vrugtehagel oh, i copied wrongly. But this is just an exercise, it can't be so hard, i'm must be doing something in a wrong way.

Comment: you want to find the generating function of .. what ?  by integration ..?

Comment: @GCab integration which series coefficients are $H_k/k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I understand that, given
$$
A(z) = {1 \over {1 - z}}\ln \left( {{1 \over {1 - z}}} \right) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {H_{\,k} \,z^{\,k} }  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {H_{\,k} \,z^{\,k} } 
$$
where the $H$ do not mean the Harmonic numbers, and $H_0=0$,
then you want to find
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {{{H_{\,k} } \over k}\,z^{\,k} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{H_{\,k + 1} } \over {k + 1}}\,z^{\,k + 1} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {H_{\,k + 1} \int_0^z {t^{\,k} dt} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_0^z {\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {H_{\,k + 1} t^{\,k} } } \right)d} t = \int_0^z {\left( {t^{\, - 1} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {H_{\,k + 1} t^{\,k + 1} } } \right)d} t = \int_0^z {{1 \over t}A(t)dt}  \cr} 
$$

Making the substitution
$$
1 - u = {1 \over {1 - t}}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad u = {{ - t} \over {1 - t}}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad
 t = 1 - {1 \over {1 - u}} = {{ - u} \over {1 - u}}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad dt =  - {{du} \over {\left( {1 - u} \right)^{\,2} }}
$$
we get
$$
\int_{t = 0}^z {{1 \over t}A(t)dt}  = \int_{u = 0}^{z/\left( {z - 1} \right)} {{1 \over u}\ln (1 - u)du}  =  - {\rm Li}_2 \left( {{z \over {z - 1}}} \right)
$$

where $ {\rm Li}_2$ denotes the [Dilogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence's_function).

Comment: @Yola: thanks, the hint for that substitution came  from $A(t)d(\ln t)$.